# Query USB current

Tags: usb, devices

How can I obtain information about the amount of current negotiated by a device attached to a USB port?

I am looking for information similar to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/38899) presented by OS X in terms of current available and current required.

Comment: What OS are you looking for this info in particular? Which distros?

Comment: debian based OS -- specifically raspbian wheezy for raspberry pi but general information would be great if possible

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the command `lsusb`. Specifically `lsusb -v` or `lsusb -vv`. Check the man page for it as well.

For example here's a wireless mouse on my laptop (Fedora 14):

```
% sudo lsusb -v
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c521 Logitech, Inc. Cordless Mouse Receiver
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x046d Logitech, Inc.
  idProduct          0xc521 Cordless Mouse Receiver
  bcdDevice           57.01
  iManufacturer           1 Logitech
  iProduct                2 USB Receiver
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           59
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 RR57.01_B0023
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower               98mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      67
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              10
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      79
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              10
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Comment: I think I was able to query similar information from `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/1-1/bMaxPower`, however, can I find how much power a device is currently receiving?

Comment: Yes that is the information from the kernel that lsusb is pulling to display. BTW, I search for a while and wasn't able to find anyway to get the power draw of device.

Comment: ah okay. thanks. strange that its possible to find on windows/mac but not linux...

Comment: I agree. I'm not convinced the info being displayed in windows is actually any more accurate. I think it's just showing the amount of power the device is reporting it wants/needs, which is the same thing that lsusb is showing as MaxPower. See this post for more: http://superuser.com/questions/297959/how-do-you-check-how-much-power-a-usb-port-can-deliver

Comment: so MaxPower is the amount of power requested by the device... ok. It would be nice to have how much power is available too, but it's better than nothing I guess

Comment: I believe per the USB spec a USB hub has 500ma available. 4 ports max, 100ma per port, plus 100ma is reserved for the hub itself. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5581/4251

Comment: Yeah thats the USB spec, but on a device with lower power availability, it doesn't always reach this amount.  The original Rpi 2.0 limited USB to 140mA and I doubt the newer model I have can supply the full 500mA x 2 ports since there is a 1.1A fuse to the device which normally draws about 700mA on its own.  I also have it attached to a lower current power supply so it definitely wouldnt be able to provide .5A of current to each USB.  Will flag as answered for now though since I dont seem to be able to find any better approaches right now.

Comment: Yeah, I think you need to be careful with the Raspberry Pi in terms of how it follows the USB spec. I was at a ARM Developer's Day talk in November 2012 (http://3rdarmdeveloperday.eventbrite.com/) where Rob Bishop, the original hardware designer talked, and I remember him saying that the Pi deviated from the spec. They're discussing it as well in this Pi forum, http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=6187&p=80651

Comment: One can use `lsusb -v 2>/dev/null | grep '^Bus\|MaxPower'` to get a more concise output (just two lines per device).